# How to create (and then get elements) array / list of Lists?

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, arraylist

How to create array or list of Lists in Java?

I have:

```
List<Item> rows = new ArrayList<Item>();

rows.add(new Item("a"));
rows.add(new Item("b"));
```

... and how to create array of lists like this above?

```
List<Item> lists[] = {};
lists[0] = rows;
```

---

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public static List<List<Item>> lists;
    String tabs[] = { "Tab 1", "Tab 2" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lists = new ArrayList<List<Item>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
        {
            lists.add(i, init());
        }
    }

    public List<Item> init()
    {
        List<Item> rows = new ArrayList<Item>();

        rows.add(new Item("test"));

        return rows;
    }

}
```

... and then I am trying to get that list by using:

```
MainActivity.lists.get(0);
```

Comment: You should initialize the static lists in `static` block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not create an array of generics types, because [it's not type safe](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ104). Here's a quote from that link

> Parameterized types do not have exact runtime type information.  As a consequence, the **array store check does not work because it uses the dynamic type** information regarding the array's (non-exact) component type for the array store check.

Emphasis mine.

Basically, array uses a *store check* at runtime, to check whether the elements stored in it, is *compatible* with the type of *actual* array. Now, since a generic type doesn't have actual type information at runtime due to *type erasure*, the array store check won't work.

E.g. (Taken from the above link):

```
Pair<Integer,Integer>[] intPairArr = new Pair<Integer,Integer>[10]; // illegal
Object[] objArr = intPairArr; 
objArr[0] = new Pair<String,String>("",""); // should fail, but would succeed
```

It would work because `Pair<Integer, Integer>[]`, is actually `Pair[]` at runtime, and will successfully store `Pair<String, String>`, which is also a `Pair` at runtime.

But that would fail further in your code, once you try to fetch elements from array.

---

So, you should rather create a *list* of *list*:

```
List<List<Item>> itemList = new ArrayList<List<Item>>();
itemList.add(rows);
```

Comment: I am creating an app for Android, and I want to use this variable globaly, as a static variable. When variable is set, I want to get one list by using .get() method, but my app is crashing. Could you provide example with setting static variable using list of list, and then adding a example list?

Comment: @Damian. How are you getting the list? Can you post your code in your question?

Comment: Okey, updated, code is compiling, but when I launch the app it is crashing.

Comment: @Damian. See my comment on your question. Use a `static` block to initialize the list. This will ensure that the list is not `null` when loaded.

Comment: Like this? static { lists = new ArrayList<List<Item>>(); }

Comment: @Damian. Yup. Like that. And if possible, populate it there only, if you are going to populate it only once.

Comment: What do you mean by `array`? Where are you using it?

Comment: I am analyzing each line of my app, I was wrong, there is something, and I am going to find it, and even if it will still crash because of lists, I will accept your answer, anyway thank you very much for your help and time.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can create List of List

```
List<List<Item>> listOfList = new ArrayList<List<Item>>();
listOfList.add(new ArrayList<Item>());
listOfList.get(0).add(new Item());
```

and List of array

```
List<Item[]> listOfArray = new ArrayList<Item[]>();
listOfArray.add(new Item[] { item1, item2});
```